# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str' winappdbg error after cx_freeze

Tags: python, pywin32, cx-freeze, docstring

i used cx_freeze to freeze my myScript.py script, it runs fine on my english win7 x64 , but after cx_freeze, on a chinese win7 x64, it shows the following error message.  i ran the same frozen code on a clean installed english win7 x64 in a vm, no error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "myScript.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "myScript.pyx", line 62, in init myScript (myScript.c:23212)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\__init__.py", line 234, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\breakpoint.py", line 66, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\process.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\disasm.py", line 631, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\winappdbg\disasm.py", line 651, in Disassembler
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

i then checked the file [disasm.py](http://sourceforge.net/p/winappdbg/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/winappdbg/disasm.py#l651) in winappdbg code, at that line, the code is

```
# Add the list of supported disassemblers to the docstring.
__doc__ += "\n"
for e in engines:
__doc__ += " - %s - %s (U{%s})\n" % (e.name, e.desc, e.url)
del e
```

i guess if i change this line of code, and re cx_freeze my code, the error will probably go way.
but how come `__doc__` is None here? isn't it the docstring of the package and always has something ?

[image]

Comment: Python code byte-compiled with an optimisation flag has docstrings stripped out. But I'm not sure how that could change with a frozen exe moving between two computers.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas K pointed out in a comment, frozen Python code is often optimized and contains no docstrings. WinAppDbg simply wasn't designed for that use case, so you'll have to patch it there (and potentially in a few more places).

If you do happen to make that patch, let me know so I can merge it :)